# How to prevent Windows 8 turning off bluetooth power?

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth

I have a Samsung 700 tablet onto which I've just installed Windows 8. My bluetooth device enters an error state shortly after installing its drivers. I've had this issue before and on a previous version of Windows was able to prevent the issue by deselecting "Allow the computer to turn this device to save power" in Device Manager -> Bluetooth Radios -> Bluetooth module -> Properties -> Power Management.

Now in Windows 8, these modules have been replaced by the heavily simplified Win RT interface. Does anyone know how I would perform the same step in Windows 8?

Answer (score 2):

You can still get to that same UI.

Press Windows+X, then click Device Manager.

Comment: But the power management features are no longer there....Even with the latest drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Samsung Ativ 500T user, here's what to do. Swipe on the right side of your screen to open Charms, press Settings, then press Change PC Settings. On the list on the left side, choose Wireless, now you have an option to turn off the Bluetooth of your Windows 8 device.